# Average in map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to calculate average of numbers in hadoop stand alone setup. I am not able to run the program. But program compile without any error and jar file also created.I think I am using correct commands to execute the program in hadoop set up. Somebody please review my code and tell me is there any problem . Here is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
  class sum_count{
    int sum;
    int count;  
  }
public class Average {


  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Object>{

    private final static IntWritable valueofkey = new IntWritable();
    private Text word = new Text();
    sum_count sc=new sum_count();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      int sum=0;
      int count=0;
      int v;
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        v=Integer.parseInt(word.toString());
        count=count+1;
        sum=sum+v;       
      }
      //valueofkey.set(sum);
      word.set("average");

      sc.sum=sum;
      sc.count=count;

    // context.write(word, valueofkey);
     // valueofkey.set(count);
      //  word.set("count");
      context.write(word,sc);
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,Object,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    private IntWritable test=new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<sum_count> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      int count=0;
      int wholesum=0;
      int wholecount=0;
      for (sum_count val : values) {
        //value=val.get();
        wholesum=wholesum+val.sum;
        wholecount=wholecount+val.count;
      }
      int res=wholesum/wholecount;
      result.set(res);
      context.write(key, result );
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "");
    job.setJarByClass(Average.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
manu@manu-Latitude-E5430-vPro:~/hadoop-2.7.2$ ./bin/hadoop jar av.jar Average bin/user/hduser/input bin/user/hduser/out12
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
16/07/01 11:19:05 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local276107063_0001
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local276107063_0001
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
16/07/01 11:19:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local276107063_0001_m_000000_0
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local276107063_0001_m_000001_0
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
16/07/01 11:19:06 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local276107063_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:132)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sum_count
    at Average$TokenizerMapper.<init>(Average.java:24)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sum_count
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 14 more
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local276107063_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local276107063_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
16/07/01 11:19:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Comment: You should describe in detail what " not able to run the program" means. Do you get error messages? Empty output? Maybe posting the commands you use to execute the program would be useful, as they might be erroneous even if you think they're correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `ClassNotFoundException` on `sum_count`. Having two classes declared at the top level of a file isnt really a good way to structure your code. It looks like when the `TokenizerMapper` tries to create that class, it can't find it on the class path.

I would just put that class in a file of its own. It will need changing anyway, your job won't work as you have it since `sum_count` doesnt `implement` the `Writable` interface. It should look more like:

```
public class SumCount implements Writable {

    public int sum;
    public int count;

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(sum);
        out.writeInt(count);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        sum = in.readInt();
        count = in.readInt();
    }  
}
```

In your `main()` you also need to tell it what types of Key/Value it will write out are:

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(SumCount.class);
```

Note the change in class name. See the Java naming convention docs [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: A new problem arised , Please answer this question,    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177609/output-file-contains-mapperoutput-instead-of-reducer-output