# Output file contains Mapper Output instead of Reducer output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I am trying to find average of few numbers using map reduce technique in stand alone mode. I have two input files.It contain values file1: `25 25 25 25 25` and file2: `15 15 15 15 15`.

My program is working fine but the output file contains output of the mapper instead of reducer output.

Here is my code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import java.io.*;


public class Average {

    public static class SumCount implements Writable {

        public int sum;
        public int count;

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            out.writeInt(sum);
            out.writeInt(count);
        }

        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            sum = in.readInt();
            count =in.readInt();
        }  
    }
  public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Object>{

    private final static IntWritable valueofkey = new IntWritable();
    private Text word = new Text();
    SumCount sc=new SumCount();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      int sum=0;
      int count=0;
      int v;
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        v=Integer.parseInt(word.toString());
        count=count+1;
        sum=sum+v;       
      }
      word.set("average");
      sc.sum=sum;
      sc.count=count;
      context.write(word,sc);
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,Object,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<SumCount> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      int count=0;
      int wholesum=0;
      int wholecount=0;
      for (SumCount val : values) {
        wholesum=wholesum+val.sum;
        wholecount=wholecount+val.count;
      }
      int res=wholesum/wholecount;
      result.set(res);
      context.write(key, result );
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "");
    job.setJarByClass(Average.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(SumCount.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

after i run the program my output file is like this:

```
average Average$SumCount@434ba039
average Average$SumCount@434ba039
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use your Reducer class `IntSumReducer` as a combiner. A combiner must receive and emit the same Key/Value types.

So i would remove `job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);`.

Remember the output from the combine is the input to the reduce, so writing out `Text` and `IntWritable` isnt going to work.

If your output files looked like `part-m-xxxxx` then the above issue could mean it only ran the Map phase and stoppped. Your counters would confirm this.

You also have `Reducer<Text,Object,Text,IntWritable>` which should be `Reducer<Text,SumCount,Text,IntWritable>`.

Comment: 1. so should i write another class for combiner ...? 

2. should i change Text IntWritable to Text Object ...?

Comment: The same problem exist after i removed the line         job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);      please help

Comment: Your combine would need different logic to the Reduce, so just remove it. Are the output files named `part-m-` or `part-r-`?